# Animating from one element to another

Tags: css, animation

I'm currently studying material design for a new website project.

I'm pretty much a back end coder but although UI stuff is outside of my comfort zone, it's something I can do once I understand the principles.

I came across this page - scroll down to the Morph section:

https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#types-of-transitions

As you can see a button morphs into another object, in this case a tuner control. The object isn't important but I need to understand the basics of how something like this would usually be achieved.

Is it just a case of scaling the button to zero size, while simultaneously scaling the tuner to full size or am I missing something important?

Comment: From what the gif (and this one: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/4874/screenshots/2101776/dribbble-morph.gif) looks like to me, it seems that the icon changes and the button moves to the center. And then background part grows with `overflow: hidden` and the `border-radius` stays the same, allowing a sort of filling effect. As for the other direction, it seems to just be the reverse effect

Answer (score 1):

Here
https://inbox.google.com/ (you need to be log to see it)

You have this type of button implemented by Google.

They are using transform scale to the grow effect for the buttons and also they have a different delay transition for every single button.

I hope helps!